# Can the duality gap be infinite?

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems, non-convex-optimization

Given a primal problem
$$ \min_{x \in \mathbf{R}^2} \{ f(x)|g(x)=0 \}
$$
that has a solution $f(x^*)=0$ (where $x^*$ is the value of x that minimizes $f$ such that $g(x)=0$),

and given a dual function
$$ \mathcal{D}(\lambda) = \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}^2}  \mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = -\infty$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lagrangian, we have that the Dual Problem is:
$$
\sup \mathcal{D}(\lambda) = -\infty  \quad \text{(I think)}
$$
**Does this imply that the duality gap is $\infty$?**

Note: the infimum of the Lagrangian can be $-\infty$ if $f$ is non-convex.

Comment: That is indeed the implication if the dual function is $-\infty$ for all $\lambda$.

Comment: Ok thanks @LinAlg. I wasn't sure if the duality gap would be "undefined" in this case. But if the supremum of $-\infty$ is $-\infty$ then the duality gap is also $-\infty$. If you want to post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Technically, the dual is infeasible. Since the primal is feasible, the primal has to be unbounded. It doesn't make much sense to talk about the duality gap.

Comment: When comparing the primal to the dual in my example, the result is $0 \ge -\infty$, which is true. But I agree, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to talk about the duality gap - I'm just trying to understand it conceptually.